# Renault modus 1.5 DCI imobilser will not go off

Tags: immobilizer

I have recently bought a 2005 Renault modus 1.5 DCI.The dash board displayed 'steering fault' which rendered power steering off.
After leaving lights on over night,the battery was drained.I then disconected battery and charged.when I went to start it the red imobilser light stayed static.. And car will not start

I have had key reprogrammed... No joy
I have pressed central locking buttons whilst turning key...no joy

Is there anyway of overriding imobilser so I can take it to a Renault garage for diagnostic reading

Or can we reset imobilser?
Thanks in advance
Paul

Comment: I imagine you have resolved this issue.  Could you post how you fixed this as answer to this question and award yourself the answer by hitting the checkbox to left of your answer once you input it?  Thanks and Happy New Year!